# SD error bars incorrect

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I have problem with the error bars in the figure. Here is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
val1 <- sample(1:18)
val2 <- sample(20:50, 18)
mylet<-c("A", "B", "C")
time <-rep(mylet,times=6)
id<-rep(c("WT", "KO"), each=9)
x1 <- data.frame(id, time, val1, val2)
x1$id=factor(x1$id, c("WT","KO"))

cols = c(3,4)
df1  = transform(x1, mean=rowMeans(x1[cols]), sd=apply(x1[cols],1, sd))

p<-ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=as.factor(time), y=mean, fill=id)) +  
  geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour="black") +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean-sd, ymax= mean+sd), width=0.2, position=position_dodge(0.9))
p
```

And here is the figure obtained

[image]

Comment: what is the question/problem ?

Comment: I have too many standard deviation points, one errorbar goes below 0 and the second red bar has two errorbars

Comment: It seems like you're missing a stratification.  You have three lines for each combination of `id` and `time`, and your plot is showing three error bars for each combination.  The bigger question is why do you have three standard deviations for each combination?  How are they different?

Comment: Yes I have just realised it, the plot is correct, it takes the mean 18 times for val1 and val2. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in variable `df1` you have multiple measurements for each (`id`, `time`) combination (for example, for id WT and time A, you have the points corresponding to mean values of 13.0, 30.5, and 15.0). You need to decide how to deal with this level of replication, whether to represent it in the figure, or to show the stats over it. Since you know the details of the experimental design, and it is your data, you should be the one making that judgement...

As an example, averaging over the multiple points for each (`id`, `time`) combination:

```
library(plyr)
df2 <- ddply(df1, c("id", "time"), summarize, mean.overall = mean(mean), sd.overall = sd(mean))
```

and then plotting via:

```
p <- 
    ggplot(data = df2, aes(x = as.factor(time), y = mean.overall, fill = id)) + 
    geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat = "identity", colour = "black") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean.overall-sd.overall, ymax = mean.overall + sd.overall), width = 0.2, position = position_dodge(0.9))
p
```

will produce a figure with properly arranged error bars. Just keep in mind that the stats here were obtained by averaging over the 3 points for each (`id`, `time`) combination

Comment: That was exactly what I was trying to do- Thank you